# How to stop NGINX spawning new instances

Tags: nginx, memory, phusion-passenger

So a bit of background, I'm running a little web app using just in-memory data. It's about 20 rows all-in so I've removed the database to speed things up.

Just recently I deployed it on a Raspberry Pi, mostly to see if I could. However it's thrown up an issue with NGINX deployment.

It looks like, as a remedy against memory leaks, NGINX dumps the application instance every 12 hours or so and starts up a new one.

*Edit:* As requested by @gf_, The result is that any in-memory data being used by my app is lost, and the re-initialisation of my environment rebuilds the default data set. The server logs show a different pid by the timestamp.

Is there a way to stop this happening? Or increase the time between occurrences? Or set a threshold for memory usage?

I'm using NGINX with the Passenger module to deploy a Rails 4 application on Raspian.

Comment: Nginx do not restart child processes at will. It's something in your config or environment.

Comment: I'm sure it is, but what, exactly?

Comment: "[...] NGINX dumps the application instance every 12 hours or so and starts up a new one [...]": Please elaborate. What happens exactly?

Comment: @AlexeyTen He's using a third party module Passenger. That's probably what the problem is. I don't recommend Passenger, for obvious reasons. Use a proper Rack web server such as thin or unicorn.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That was one of the least helpful comments I've ever seen on the internet. "How do I lose weight?" "Have less gravity"... Obviously I'm in the situation I'm in and trying to fix a known problem. You just tell me it's 'obviously wrong' and don't even suggest an alternative. Perhaps de-high-horse yourself and actually suggest a solution of some variety?

Comment: I did suggest _two_ solutions!

Comment: @MichaelHampton You modified your comment, which at least gives me some leads, now. But I seriously recommend against telling people "For obvious reasons, you're wrong". What, exactly, do you dislike about Passenger, by the way?

Comment: Stop right there. I never said anything about you being wrong. You should not take a technical comment about some software personally. As for Passenger, its primary problem is that it makes its host web server unpredictable and much more difficult to manage and maintain (which I  had thought should be obvious by now).

Comment: @MichaelHampton, it's not obvious why you wouldn't recommend Passenger.